# Write a custom decorator to check if session is active in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions

Is this possible to write a decorator to check if a specific request session exists? Like user id. If not redirect to another page. Similar to login_required decorator.

```
@session_active('user_id')
def HomeView(request):
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: isn't the login information stored in the session? (i.e. if login_required then there has to be a session..?)

Comment: login require is different. It checks if user is authenticated. I need to check if a specific session vatiable exists

Comment: no login_required checks if a user is logged in (there's a pedantic difference ;-)  If you want to check if a session variable exists then just access it and catch the exception.

Comment: login_required actually uses user_passes_test. Well I can't use that since The user is always anonymous since I have implemented a custom authentication backend

Comment: If you've implemented the custom authentication backend properly, then `authenticate(..)` + `login(request, user)` should still set `request.user` for you.. (better not to fight too hard against Django ;-)

Comment: i cannot substitute a custom user model because passwords and users are in different tables also  i cannot run migrations for my existing tables. when I specify AUTH_USER_MODEL, django complains about migrations. That's why I gave up. I got rid of the login function completely and work with the session framework.